# Python numpy: Simplify operation on multiple matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3 numpy matrices:

One contains pixels positions in X (`x_pos`), another pixel positions in Y (`y_pos`) and a last one containing pixel values (`p_value`)

I would like to use these 3 matrices to build a results image

With loops I have this result:

```
#Resulting image
res = np.zeros((128,128,3), dtype = np.uint8)

for i in range(x_pos.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x_pos.shape[1]):

        # Get coordinates
        x = x_pos[i][j]
        y = y_pos[i][j]
            
        res[y,x] = p_value[i][j]
```

With large matrices (2048*2048) this code already takes a lot of time. Is it possible to optimize this code without using a nested loop?

I specify that the positions in the `pos_x` and `pos_y` matrices do not necessarily follow each other, there may be holes or duplicate values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible using `np.meshgrid`

```
i = np.arange(0, x.shape[0])
j = np.arange(0, x.shape[1])

i_1, j_1 = np.meshgrid(i, j, indexing='ij')
res[y_1.ravel(),x_1.ravel()] = p_value[i_1.ravel(),j_1.ravel()]
```

Answer (score 1):

First use consistent `numpy` 2d array indexing:

```
    x = x_pos[i,j]
    y = y_pos[i,j]    
    res[y,x] = p_value[i,j]
```

Now instead of scalar i,j use arrays

```
 i = np.arange(n); j = np.arange(m)
```

You didn't provida [mcve] so I won't try to demonstrate that th

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @hpaulj and @ai2ys answer the problem is solved.

Here is a comparison of the results in terms of execution speed:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

m_size = 4096
m_x = np.random.randint(0,m_size,(m_size,m_size), dtype = np.uint16)
m_y = np.random.randint(0,m_size,(m_size,m_size), dtype = np.uint16)
p_value = np.ones((m_size,m_size), dtype = np.uint8)

#Meshgrid method:
out = np.zeros((m_size,m_size),dtype=np.uint8)

start = time.time()
i = np.arange(0, m_x.shape[0])
j = np.arange(0, m_x.shape[1])

i_1, j_1 = np.meshgrid(i, j, indexing='ij')
out[m_x.ravel(),m_y.ravel()] = p_value[i_1.ravel(),j_1.ravel()]

end = time.time()
print("Meshgrid: {} s".format(end - start))

#No for loop method:
out = np.zeros((m_size,m_size),dtype=np.uint8)

start = time.time()
i = np.arange(m_x.shape[0])
j = np.arange(m_y.shape[1])

x = m_x[i,j]
y = m_y[i,j]
out[x,y] = p_value[i,j]

end = time.time()
print("No loop: {} s".format(end - start))


#For loop method:
out = np.zeros((m_size,m_size),dtype=np.uint8)
start = time.time()
for i in range(m_x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(m_y.shape[1]):
        x = m_x[i,j]
        y = m_y[i,j]
        out[x,y] = p_value[i,j]
end = time.time()
print("Nested loop: {} s".format(end - start))


#Output:
Meshgrid: 0.4837045669555664 s
No loop: 0.3600656986236572 s
Nested loop: 13.10097336769104 s
```